Update Profile Picture works for seeder account but not real user account
so i am trying to make a website using laravel and for there's upload profile picture feature but somehow it only works for a seeder account but not real account and i am not quite sure why. when i check the file that is send by real account always stuck in laravel temp file and i've tried deleting validator to see if it works but it still didn't work
here is my code
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Fortify;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\UpdatesUserProfileInformation;

class UpdateUserProfileInformation implements UpdatesUserProfileInformation
{
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($user, array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:1024'],
        ])->validateWithBag('updateProfileInformation');

        if (isset($input['photo'])) {
            $user->updateProfilePhoto($input['photo']);
        }

        if (
            $input['email'] !== $user->email &&
            $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail
        ) {
            $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $input);
        } else {
            $user->forceFill([
                'name' => $input['name'],
                'username'  => $input['username'],
                'email' => $input['email'],
            ])->save();
        }
    }

can someone let me know how to fix it, this is my first time building a web
i've tried deleting the validation

To handle files you should use Laravel's Request instance instead of just getting the path string from converting it to array
public function update($user, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username'  => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:1024'],
        ])->validateWithBag('updateProfileInformation');

        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $user->updateProfilePhoto($request->file('photo'));
        }

        if (
            $request->email !== $user->email &&
            $user instanceof MustVerifyEmail
        ) {
            $this->updateVerifiedUser($user, $request->all());
        } else {
            $user->forceFill([
                'name' => $request->name, 
//here you can use $request->get('name') or $request->input('name','default_name'); or omit the default value $request->input('name');
                'username'  => $request->username,
                'email' => $request->email,
            ])->save();
        }

The in your updateProfilePhoto() method you need to handle the instance of \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile witch has methods like store()
for example
public function updateProfilePhoto(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $file->store('images/user-' . $this->id . '.' . $file->clientExtension());
}

